# file ending .gz0 - which program does this?

Tags: solaris, gzip

On my Solaris 10 boxes, I have compressed log files with the ending `.gz0`. `gunzip` cannot unzip them, however if I change the ending to `.gz`, gunzip will unzip them, and these files appear to be empty. So I see the point, however I am not aware of a program that does this. It’s probably a custom script somewhere, however I was not able to find one.

Did anyone ever encounter this file ending? Which program produces this? Google is not helpful here.

Comment: Could this be the log rotation that is simply a bit confused or wrongly configured? Note that you my decompress these files with `gunzip <file.gz0 >file` (this keeps the compressed file).

Comment: Yes, that might be the case - still, it seems some tool is calling gzip and adding a 0 to empty archives.

Comment: The log rotation config may say to rotate a `.gz` file and to add an integer suffix to the rotated files.

Comment: Yes - but that should be visible somewhere, right? logadm is not configured to do so. No other cronjob visible ...

Comment: I would search your jobs (cron, at, etc) for ones that run `gzip`; if they use `gzip -c ...` they could redirect the output to a `filename.gz0` themselves.